# REST service with JAX-RS and OData?

Tags: java, odata, jax-rs

I have been playing with some REST web services which use JAX-RS annotations.
I am now looking at using [OData](http://www.odata.org/) for our query type services.
However, I haven't see any OData examples that uses JAX-RS annotations.
In fact, OData service examples seem to look very different to JAX-RS services.

Can OData servcies be annotated with JAX-RS statements?
I can't seem to find any examples.

Thanks

Sarah

Answer (score 1):

odata4j now (0.6) support Jersey and CXF impl for OData producer. you can refer to the google code page (list above) for more detail.

Comment: OData4j provides a Jersey server that is configured to serve OData requests on a variety of data sources.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can build OData services on top of standards like JAX-RS.

Here's a [google code page](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/) that lists out the current status and links to the odata4j project.  There may be some examples there that you can use to build JAX-RS OData services.

I'm a .NET developer, so I'm not up on my Java framework capabilities, but hopefully this helps.